# How to write this For loops in R efficiently

Tags: r

I have a matrix `X` of nxp dimensions. Before I do some operations on it, I store it as `X1`. After these operations, I will check if any element of `X` is 
 negative, I replace it with its previous value from `X1`.

Currently, I am using the following code to do this.

```
      X1 <- X
      #some operations on X 
      for(i in 1:n){
        for(j in 1:p){
          if(X[i,j]< 0){
            X[i,j]<-X1[i,j]
          }
        }
      }
```

As n and p become large, this operation is taking a lot of time. Can you please suggest a efficient of writing the same.

Comment: Please provide a sample data

Comment: `ifelse(X < 0, X1, X)`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: Thank you! That solved my problem.

Comment: Even better than `ifelse` is to use a logical index: `X[X < 0] <- X1[X < 0]`.